# Knockout JS - not a function error

Tags: knockout.js

My HTML Goes like Following:

```
<td>Total Amount to be Paid: </td>
<td data-bind="text: invoiceAmount() + ' Kr'"></td>
<td>bill:</td>
<td data-bind="text: billAmount()"></td>
<td>Chosen Provision: </td>
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: chosenProvision()"/>  Kr</td>
```

JS:

```
self.invoiceAmount = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;
        if(self.selectedInvoices().length > 0){
            for(var p = 0; p < self.selectedInvoices().length; ++p)
            {
                total += Number(self.selectedInvoices()[p].invoicedArticleFinal);
            }
        }

        return total;
    });

    self.billAmount = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.invoiceAmount() + self.chosenProvision();
    });

    self.chosenProvision = ko.computed(function(){
        if(self.invoiceAmount() < 750){
            return "50";
        } else {
            return (self.invoiceAmount()*0.1);
        }
    });
```

I keep getting error: self.chosenProvision is not a function.

I also want to be able to modify the chosenProvision from browser that is why it's binding is to a input tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell knockout to wait to recalculate computed values until after the view model is defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569341/is-there-a-way-to-tell-knockout-to-wait-to-recalculate-computed-values-until-aft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify a computed, it needs to be a [writable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html).

The reason you're getting `self.chosenProvision is not a function` is that in `self.billAmount` you're using `self.chosenProvision`, which is not defined at that point. `computed`s are executed when they are created (`pureComputed`s are not)

To have a writable computed, just make your computed definition something like this:

```
self.chosenProvision = ko.computed({
 read: function(){
     if(self.invoiceAmount() < 750){
            return "50";
        } else {
            return (self.invoiceAmount()*0.1);
        }
 },
 write: function (newValue) {
     // Do whatever with newValue
 }
});
```

Comment: I have modified my question. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: Thanks but I am quite new to Knockout and don't understand the writable computed concept. I tried but it didn't work. Can you help me by modifying my code to convert the chosenProvision into pure computed observable.

Comment: @Saurabh: Just move the definition of `chosenProvision` to be before that of `billAmount`.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty clear from your first comment also that computed are executed when they are created and I am trying to use a computed variable before it's creation. Some times I just over read and look for a prepared answer. Thanks Again. It's solved now.

Comment: I also want to modify chosen provision value from browser. Do you know how that can be done ?

Comment: @saurabh What do you want to happen when you get a new value for chosenProvision?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84011/discussion-between-saurabh-and-roy-j).