# why computed function runs automatically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one knockout computed function like this in my code

```
 self.TestFunction = ko.computed(function () {
            //Some logic
        }, self).extend({ rateLimit: 100 });
```

This function is executed automatically without its been binded to any html element. I would like to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell knockout to wait to recalculate computed values until after the view model is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569341/is-there-a-way-to-tell-knockout-to-wait-to-recalculate-computed-values-until-aft)

Comment: You can use [`pureComputed`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) instead. This will calculate only when it's being observed or has subscribers

Comment: Are you asking how KO runs subscriptions without having an HTML binding or why this is being executed when you think it shouldn't be?

Comment: @VLAZ i am asking how KO runs subscriptions without having html binding.

Comment: @James ok, in that case...why shouldn't it? A subscription is against JS objects and there is no issue having JS objects refer to and affect each other. Why would you need an HTML binding for that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know the reason behind it

Usually, you use a `ko.computed` for its return value. *However*, this isn't their only use. Often, you'll see code using a `ko.computed` more like a fancy way to `subscribe` to multiple values. For example

```
// Please note, I do *not* recommend these kinds of structures, I'm merely
// showing knockout allows them
const input1 = ko.observable("");
const input2 = ko.observable("");
const input3 = ko.observable("");

ko.computed(function someSideEffect() {
  input1();
  input2();
  input3();

  console.log("Some value has changed!");
});
```

Now, for knockout to be able to "run" the side effect of logging to console, it has to find out what its dependencies are. It does so by running the `someSideEffect` function *once*.

As mentioned in the comments, `pureComputed` properties work differently. They only run their inner function once their *own* value is requested.

In short:

- `ko.computed` runs its inner function upon creation because it supports side-effects.
- `ko.pureComputed` only runs once when its value is requested, and pauses when there are no dependencies.